# C++ class nested into template class

Tags: c++

So I have some problems with my template class.

```
<!-- language: lang-c++ -->

template<class T>
class List {
  class Counter
  {       
    T real;
    T imaginary;
    Counter *next;
 //....
  public:
    Counter(T a=0,T b=0);                  
    virtual ~Counter();                     
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,Counter&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,List&);
  };
  Counter* first;
  Counter* last;
//....
};
```

But I have some problems with methods. If i write function as

```
template<class T> Counter operator/(Counter &one,...)
```

When I look at Counter in VC++10 it says something like

```
<error_type>&one
```

for example. Should I use `template<class T>` for my Counter class everywhere in the code?

```
//Methods
//Counter. For example some methods
Counter operator/(Counter& one,Counter& two){}
ostream& operator<<(ostream&os,Counter&x){}
istream& operator>>(istream&is,Counter&x){}
 //List
template<class T>void List<T>::add(Counter *T,int i,bool c){}
```

Comment: Yes you should. Unless you define you functions inline you need to provide template arguments for each and every method definition.

Comment: As far as I know, yes if you need to use the template class in Counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you define the operators (regardless of whether they are member functions or global operators) *inside* the class definition or *outside* of it.

If you do it inside the class definition, there is no need for `template<T>`, nor for `List<T>`:

```
template <typename T>
class List
{
public:
  class Counter
  {
    /* This is a global operator* defined inside the class, and
       as friend. */
    friend Counter operator*(const Counter &c1, const Counter &c2)
    {
      return Counter();
    }
  };

};
```

(Note that my definition of `operator*` isn't actually useful because it always returns an empty `Counter` object. This is just to demonstrate the syntax.)

But if you define the operator outside the class (and therefore outside the template definition for `List` as well), you have to use the full syntax of a function template definition:

```
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::Counter operator/(const typename List<T>::Counter &c1, const typename List<T>::Counter &c2)
{
  return List<T>::Counter();
}
```

As you can see, this involves three steps:

1. Put `template <....>`, with the names of all template parameters enclosed in `<`...`>` before the definition.
2. Use `List<T>::Counter` to indicate that `Counter` is a nested typename
3. Use `typename List<T>::Counter` because `Counter` is nested into a *dependent type* (i.e. a type that depends on a template argument).

Comment: So as i understood 
   
   template<class T> typename List<T>::Counter*       List<T>::Node_find(int i)
has no errors for my complier?

Comment: Well, does it? It seems correct to me, but if there is still an error, let me know.